# Forcing www version is adding ghost subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I've used this bit of code many times for my client's sites, but I'm getting a weird error on one of them. If I use this code, then try to test a non-www page to see if it will redirect, it inserts a subdirectory directly after the .com. For example, `example.com/example.html` gets redirected to `www.example.com/exa/example.html`, which is obviously a 404 error. The "exa" subdirectory doesn't even exist.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

```
# Redirect non-www urls to www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Try last line as: `RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: That didn't work. It's still directing to the subdirectory. Any other suggestions?

Comment: where is this .htaccess located and what was your original URL in browser?